# Best language/stack for making thousands of Facebook calls?

Tags: php, facebook, load-balancing

I am working on a project that requires making several thousands of Facebook API calls a day. All this data needs to be stored in a database, which the PHP Laravel based website then can use. However, I fear that PHP is not the right language to approach this, because basically what I want is to make as many calls per hour as Facebook allows, but spread out so that the load is nice and balanced.

I have heard about Ruby in combination with Sidekiq, but I am really not familiar with the pros and cons of this method. Is this what I am looking for? Or is there another approach that would suit my needs better?

Comment: I don't think changing your language will help. It seems to me that you'll want to avoid making the calls inside a web request, to keep your app fast - so just add the calls on a queue and process them in the background. You can do this on a cron (every X minutes do Y calls) or add them to a worker queue (e.g. Gearman), and ensure they are rate-limited.

Comment: I still have the idea that PHP is not the right way to go. From what I gather, PHP is mostly a webdevelopment language, whereas alternative are much more general purpose. But please do correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I think you'd be moving for the wrong reasons. It seems you'd be leaving a language you do know for one that you don't, involving a technology you've "heard of". As I've already pointed out, PHP can handle it. But, it's your decision.

Comment: In my opinion, standing by what you know is not always the best approach. If there are better alternatives out there, I think it is worth it to improve the code, instead of settling for something "that I know". Besides, I am not even sure whether we're gonna code it ourselves. Maybe we'll hire someone who has more experience. I just want the client to have the best and most effective code, and I will not settle for less. But thank you anyway for your comments, they are helpful!

Answer (score 2):

If you want "shardability" (meaning you want to spread the load evenly among multiple processes), then PHP is in fact probbably the wrong language. But, I guess, it depends on how many and how complicated calls you're trying to process.

I went for a solution for a similar task with a combination of

- NGINX as load balancer (for the incoming Realtime Updates)
- NodeJS as "application server"
- RabbitMQ as Message Queue
- Redis / MongoDB as persistence/caching layer

The nice thing about using NodeJS and MongoDB as components is that both of them can deal with the JSON results from the Graph API in a native way, meaning that you don't have to necessarily transform the JSON data in any way before using/storing it. This is a good point for speed, and with the async nature of the NodeJS event loop, you're probably able to handle much more load than with a PHP process.

Comment: +1 for Node.JS and MongoDB :)

Comment: The client's prognosis is that the project has the potential of 500.000 requests per day. This then should be distributed across multiple servers (otherwise Facebook's gonna get mad), but the principle stays the same. Thank you very much for your advice, we will definitely look into this!

Comment: You're welcome. Please keep in mind that FB has limits on app level mostly, not IP addresses AFAIK. See https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#thingstoknow no. 11

Comment: But it is possible to create multiple apps and let them all write to the same database, right?

Comment: Sure, but what you wrote doesn't indicate that you'll hit the `5M MAU, 100M API calls per day, or 50M impressions per day` limit. You're aware that there's commercial software built for exactly you use case? Just if you don't want to reinvent the wheel...

Comment: You are right, I missed the absolute figures. Will look at some commercial software as well, not really familiar with this.. Do you maybe have some examples?

Comment: One I know of is http://www.digitalsync.de/en/ for example